# The complement or the attribute in the "Love is eternal" sentence?

Tags: sentence-construction

Is the "is eternal" a complement to the love subject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your example, the word "eternal" is a *predicative complement*, as it follows the linking verb "*is*", and defines the subject "love".

> In grammar, a subject complement or predicative of the subject is a predicative expression that follows a linking verb (copula) and that complements the subject of the sentence by either (1) renaming it or (2) describing it.
>
> (from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subject_complement))